# ngResource/$resource not injected correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, ngresource

The current task is to write a client for an API. The $resource module is not getting injected correctly. I have injected ngResource to the module, and then also passed it into the factory declaration. However inside the controller, if I try to console.log($resource), I get the following error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$resource('https://ourlink.nl',options)')`

I am convinced the issue is happening/not happening in app.js, but receptive to input if you have other ideas. Can you help me spot the problem?

## restClient.js

```
function restClient ($resource) {
  'use strict';
  var options = {};

  init();

  return {
    endpoint: self.endpoint,
    sendRequest: sendRequest
  };

  function init () {
    self.endpoint = 'https://ourlink.nl';
  }

  function sendRequest () {
    $resource('https://ourlink.nl', options);
    return true;
  }

}

module.exports = restClient;
```

## app.js

```
var angular = require('angular');

// imports
require('angular-resource');

(function (angular, config, loaders, controllers, services, providers) {
      'use strict';

      angular
        .module('at.annabel', [
        'ngLocale',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngResource',
        'ngSanitize',
        'pascalprecht.translate',
        'ui.bootstrap'
      ])

    // constants
      .constant('translations', config.translations)

    // config
      .config([
        '$locationProvider',
        'config.BASE_PATH',
        providers.locationProvider
      ])

    // services
      .factory(
        'restClient',
        ['$resource', services.restClient]
      )

    // controllers
      .controller(
        'PlaceholderController',
        [controllers.PlaceholderController]
      )
    ;
}
        ))(
    angular,
    // config
    {
        menu: require('./config/menu').config
...
        }
    },
    // loaders
    {
        localeLoader: require('./config/locale-loader')
    },
    // controllers
    {
        PlaceholderController: require('./modules/placeholder/placeholder-controller')
    },
    // services
    {
        restClient: require('./services/restClient')
    },
    //providers
    {
        locationProvider: require('./config/location-provider')
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be there the whole time. Since the app does not invoke restClient.js in the browser, I was only seeing the module invoked in test. The test runner wasn't properly set up for $resource, and $resource needed to be injected into the module by the test. Thanks to everyone who took the time to read and investigate. I got caught up on the app.js file, because it is so unconventional, but turns out the whole file is legit.